# Entity Framework lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

В [учебнике](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php) написано что при lazy loading'е при первом обращении к свойству оно подгружается из БД. Но вот я лично получал вместо нужного мне объекта `NullReferenceException`

```
namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Team")]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
    }    
    class TeamContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TeamContext db = new TeamContext())
            {
                var Teams = db.Teams.Where(x => x.Name == "Bovaria").ToList();
                foreach (var team in Teams)
                {
                    foreach (var Player in team.Players)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Player.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Строка подключения

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TeamContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Teamstest;Integrated Security=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

[image: Таблица команд]

[image: Таблица игроков]

[image: Сам "екзептион"]

как тогда мне подгрузить именно при помощи "Ленивой загрузки"?

Comment: team.Collection("Players").Load() или через team.Include("Players")

Comment: @cpp_user это не Lazy Load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для реализации Lazy Load EF использует наследование - генерацию прокси-наследников в динамической сборке . А у вас классы - `internal`, что явно запрещает создание наследников от них в сторонних сборках. Поменяйте на `public` и все заработает:

```
public class Team
{
    // ...
}

public class Player
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Классы, использующие ленивую загрузку должны быть публичными, а их свойства должны иметь модификаторы *public* и *virtual*.

http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Coach { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Team(){
         Players = new List<Players >();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```